# Introduce boost::exception to me

Tags: c++, exception, boost

I am asked to create "customizable exception framework" using boost::exception. Till date I used only simple exceptions defined by me. So std::exception,boost::exception are new to me. The code is below.

```
#include <iterator>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>
#include<errno.h>

struct My_exception:public virtual boost::exception
{
};

int main()
{
std::string fileName="tmp.txt";
std::string mode="r";

    try
    {
        if(fopen(fileName.c_str(),mode.c_str()))
            std::cout << " file opened " << std::endl ;
        else
        {
            My_exception e;
            e << boost::errinfo_api_function("fopen") <<   boost::errinfo_file_name(fileName)
            << boost::errinfo_file_open_mode(mode) << boost::errinfo_errno(errno);

            throw e;
        }
    }
    catch(My_exception e)
    {
    // extract the  details here //
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now, I want to know that how to extract the data from that caught exception. Can anybody guide me in the path of boost::exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your code has error, for example you cannot write this:

```
e << boost::errinfo_api_function("fopen")
```

Because `errinfo_api_function` can be used with `int` only. So do something like this:

```
  e << boost::errinfo_api_function(100) //say 100 is error code for api error
```

See the second type parameter to [`errinfo_api_function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/boost_exception_errinfo_api_function_hpp.html)<sup>1</sup>, it's `int`. Similarly, check other error class templates. I've given the link to each of them you're using, at the end of this post!

<sub>1. It seems there're two version of this class template, one which takes `int`, other which takes `const char*`. Compare [version 1.40.0 errinfo_api_function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/boost_exception_errinfo_api_function_hpp.html) with [version 1.45.0 errinfo_api_function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/exception/doc/boost_exception_errinfo_api_function_hpp.html). Thanks to [dalle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19100/dalle) who pointed it out in the comment. :-)</sub>

---

Use [get_error_info](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/get_error_info.html) function template to get data from `boost::exception`.

See what [boost::exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/exception.html) documentation says,

> To retrieve data from a
>   boost::exception object, use the
>   get_error_info function template.

---

Sample code:

```
//since second type of errinfo_file_name is std::string
std::string fileError = get_error_info<errinfo_file_name>(e); 

//since second type of errinfo_errno is int
int errno = get_error_info<errinfo_errno>(e);

//since second type of errinfo_file_open_mode is std::string
std::string mode = get_error_info<errinfo_file_open_mode>(e);

//since second type of errinfo_api_function is int
int apiError = get_error_info<errinfo_api_function>(e);
```

See these for better understanding:

- [errinfo_file_name](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/exception/doc/errinfo_file_name.html)
- [errinfo_errno](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/errinfo_errno.html)
- [errinfo_file_open_mode](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/boost_exception_errinfo_file_open_mode_hpp.html)
- [errinfo_api_function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/boost_exception_errinfo_api_function_hpp.html)

Comment: error C2065: 'errinfo_file_name' : undeclared  but I inllcuded the file #include <boost/exception/errinfo_file_name.hpp>

Comment: @prabhakaran: are you using proper namespace?

Comment: @prabhakaran: write `boost::errinfo_file_name`, likewise every other template!

Comment: @Nawaz you are right. Now I cleared so many errors except this one what is the meaning of it       "'<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'boost::errinfo_api_function'"

Comment: @Downvoter : please point out the error in my post, so that I correct it.

Comment: @Nawaz The mistake was in my side, I entered some wrong values as input, after I corrected it now it is working fine. Is it possible to put any other message(with user defined tag) into exception and retriving it

Comment: @prabhakaran: yes. you've to typedef, like this :  `typedef error_info<struct user_defined_tag, std::string> errinfo_user_defined;` and use this. See the links at the end of my post. You'll understand it by seeing them!

Comment: @prabhakaran: by the way, if it solved your problem, then mark this answer as "accepted answer". :-)

Comment: @Nawaz it is not working, it showing the message as  "missing ';' before '<'" in typedef line

Comment: @prabhakaran: are you using qualified name, as `boost::error_info`?

Comment: @Nawaz Ok,Ok,Ok,... Done , Everything is working fine. Thank you Nawaz,

Comment: `errinfo_api_function` takes a `const char*` in boost 1.45, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/exception/doc/boost_exception_errinfo_api_function_hpp.html

Comment: @dalle: the link I've given takes `int`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, but I beleive that is a documentation bug. Also, `get_error_info` returns by `const` pointer, not by value.

Comment: @dalle: I thought so when I saw the examples given there. In my opinion, string makes more sense than int because we can pass function name. But since I didn't find any class template that takes `const char*, so I didn't assume anything, and wrote confidently what made sense as per the link to documentation. :-)

Comment: @dalle: By the way, I would like to thank you for providing that link. :-)